# how to delete space in a column between numbers in python

Tags: python, pandas, csv

uploaded csv file

there is a field named "price", which looks as follows below:

```
PRICE 
435         
303         
442         
497         
528         
... 
1 129,24    
1 129,24    
1 129,24    
1 129,24    
1 129,24
```

I need to delete a *space* in a price `1 129,24`.

I tried replace, converters, skipinitialspace, strip() - none of them helped

Comment: Please add your attempts as code snippets

Comment: `print('1 129,24'.replace(' ',''))` works just fine for me.

Comment: What does the data look like in your CSV file?  Are these being read as strings, or as numbers?  If it possible that's the "standard" for your region?

Comment: Did you copy this from Excel or something? It might have formatted the numbers specially. Please make a [mre]. For specifics, see [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](/q/20109391/4518341). For other tips, check out [How to ask a good question](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 2):

assuming it's a column `'price'` within a dataframe `df`, this should work:

```
df['price'].str.replace(' ', '')
```

note this uses `pd.Series.str` to call string manipulation functions such as `.replace()` on each element of a Series